# UnicodeDecodeError Python when importing a db postgresql

Tags: python-unicode

I have looking for this error I got a tons of answers but None solved my problem.

Im triying to import some tables but some of gives this error, I dont know how to fix it

My code:

```
hostname = '192.168.0.50'
username = 'aasd
password = 'asdasd'
database = 'db1'


def doQuery( conn ):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    comando_sql = """SELECT os.numos, 
                     ccusto.nomecc,prest.nomeprest,equip.especifica
                     from osmanut as os 
                     left join cadcc as ccusto on os.codccserv = ccusto.codcc 
                     left join cadprest as prest on os.prestsolic = prest.codprest 
                     left join cadeqman as equip on os.codequipa = equip.codequipa 
                     where codtecos = '007' and CAST(os.dataconclu AS DATE) = '2017-07-05' order by os.numos"""
    cur.execute (comando_sql)
    arq = open("relatorio_diario.txt", "w")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        numos = row[0]
        setor = row[1]
        solicitante = row[2]
        equip_nome = row[3]
        solicitante = solicitante if solicitante is not None else "Nao Informado"
        equip_nome = equip_nome if equip_nome is not None else "Nao Informado"
        arq.write('_OS: {} - Setor: {} - Solicitante: {}\n - Equipamento: {}\n Resolucao: '.format(numos, setor, solicitante, equip_nome))
        arq.write("\n")
        arq.write("------------------------------------------------------")
        arq.write("\n")
    arq.close()

import psycopg2
myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```

The error I get
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 272: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Error on which line? post the full traceback

Comment: File "C:/Users/ti/Desktop/relatorio.py", line 17, in doQuery
    rows = cur.fetchall()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 272: ordinal not in range(128)